# overloaded battery burns appliance

Tags: batteries, automotive

I got a 12V car battery. I charged it with a 12 V solar panel until it gets about 17V (the battery was hot, I know that isn't good). Later on, I burned several battery-feed devices. The funny thing was that some of those devices were USB adapters for both 12 AND 24V batteries! What have I missed?

Which maximum voltage you consider safe for this kind of appliances? Do you recommend to reduce the voltage using a minimalistic voltage regulator circuit?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** mind you, the main question is why a USB charger prepared for both 12V and 24V is burned by a 17V battery. I did some research and my guess is that is related with voltage droop, maybe the actual voltage for this kind of appliances is higher in the overcharged 12V battery than in the normally charged 24V battery. But I'm unable to get the numbers by myself.

Comment: Your forgot that a 12V solar panel is not 12V , it's a current source with up to 85% Voc and you must protect the battery from boiling the electrolyte with a series Voltage regulator ANd your appliance will dissipate according to voltage squared and appropriate heat sinks may be needed

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 What does "85% Voc" mean here? Open circuit voltage is 85% of what?

Comment: It means array voltage at 85% of no load or open cct voltage

Answer (score 0):

According to automotive standards (ISO 16949 for example), a 12V-device should operate between 9 and 16VDC input without any problems. So 17VDC seems a bit excessive for some sensitive devices.

Anyway, a car battery should show 14.5V maximum when fully charged.

Comment: 14.2 is preferred Vmax v

Comment: And it is not given the burnt devices conform this standard..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments given here some more information.
The maximum voltage of a fully charged 12V car battery (lead accid) does not exceed 14.4 V plus or minus a very small tolerance.

However when the charging proces is not stopped by a regulator the proces keeps going on and the battery absorbs the incomming energy by getting hot and boiling of water and some electrolyte vapour.

At the moment that the plates of the battery cells become free from the electrolyte the voltage limitation of 14.4 V is no longer there and the voltage of the battery goes up as long as the charging continues up to the maximum voltage of the charger.

This proces took place in your situation since there was obviously no voltage regulator to stop the charging proces at the moment that the battery has reached the 14.4V maximum.